# How to select all from table and replace null?

Tags: sql

How do I write the code to select all from a table but if column x has a null then replace it with a value from column y? in sql?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: put the table definition,insert queries and also whatever other queries  you have tried along with this question

Comment: Have you tried coalesce. Read here: https://docs.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/33405.htm

Comment: A simple search on google and you can find a lot of answers. Check [COALESCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) or [ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) or a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(x, y) 
FROM Table;
```

This simply return the first non null values, and it exists in a lot of RDBMS, like SQL Server, Mysql, and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE`. It takes 2 or more argruments. Where as it looks for the first parameter. If that is null, it takes the next and so forth

Read more here about [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)

```
Select ColA,ColB,COALESCE(ColX,ColY) as ColXY from TableA
```